# read haar cascade in distribute mode in hadoop

Tags: opencv, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV library for image detection in Hadoop using Spark framework.
I am able to run the spark program in local mode where Haar file is present in local file system.
But I am getting null pointer error for reading the Haar file in distributed mode Although I have copied haar file in all the cluster nodes and provided the absolute path in the code.

```
String fileloc ="/home/centos/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(fileloc);

Error: 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.guessLength(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:658)
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseBase64Binary(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:696)
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.parseBase64Binary(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:438)
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:342)
        at com.lb.customlogic.impl.CustomLogicImpl.process(CustomLogicImpl.java:82)
        ... 20 more
```

I have tried with prefix extensions file://, file:/ and file:/// but those are not working out for me.
Do I need to add anything extra in the prefix to get the file read during execution of the program ?
Since Opencv has no support for Hadoop, I think I can't provide the HDFS shared location path for haar file.

Comment: Can I use --files in spark-submit to read the haar file in executors. I checked the theoretical definition of  --files option but I am not sure about its implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved after adding --files parameter in spark-submit.
haar file is distributed across all the nodes. we just need to provide file name in source code:

```
String fileloc ="haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(fileloc);
```